# set custom PATH for npm

Tags: node.js, npm, path, npm-scripts

Is there a way that I can add a directory to the **PATH** of npm. I DON'T want to add this directory to the machine **PATH**, just the one npm uses when running scripts.
I know that npm adds `node_modules/.bin` in addition to any pre-existing machine **PATH** (see [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script))

To give more detail on my specific case. I have a project with nested directories, each with its own `package.json`. When running a script on a sub-directory which depends on a parent binary, the binary won't be found because it's not on the local `node_modules/.bin` but inside a parent `node_modules/.bin`.
I could specify the path to the binary inside the script but this is cumbersome and makes the scripts less readable.

So, is there a way to tell npm to export **PATH** before running every script? It's already doing something like this to add the local `node_modules/.bin`

Comment: Do you plan to hard code this additional directory into **PATH**, or would you want it to automatically traverse parent directories for `node_modules/.bin` folders?

Comment: @gregnr Either way works for me. I think that automatically traverse parent directories would be the preferred way, but I would settle for hardcoding the directory into **PATH** (but only for `npm` and not for the machine shell, i.e. using the subdirectory `package.json` or `npmrc` to set it if that's possible)

Comment: I'm referring to a `node` script as [this link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) says (which I also linked on the question itself). Those are the scripts run with `npm run ...`. The 5th paragraph says that npm adds `node_modules/.bin` to the **PATH** before running any script. I want to add other directories to that particular **PATH** that it's modified before each script is run. Or make npm traverse parent directories adding those to the **PATH** automatically. All this without modifying the machine shell PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any simple way to accomplish what you are describing.

You can set/modify environment variables right before a script like:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "parent-script": "PATH=$PATH:/path/to/parent/node_modules/.bin parent-script"
  }
}
```

But as you mentioned this is cumbersome to do this on every script. Also you might as well just do as you described:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "parent-script": "/path/to/parent/node_modules/.bin/parent-script"
  }
}
```

A complicated, but possibly more maintainable approach could be to build yourself a `search-script` Node module that will traverse parent directories for a script passed as an argument, then run it:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "search-script": "^0.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "parent-script": "search-script parent-script"
  }
}
```

Unfortunately NPM does not provide a lot of flexibility for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can see is creating a shell script called npm, place it in a folder in your PATH and remove npm from your PATH and have your shell script set the parent binary dir in your PATH and call the npm binary passing the rest of args. It's not really worth it and might cause other issues.

I would just add all those binaries your scripts in nested folders depend on in their own package.json, which in some ways is worth it, specially if you want to deploy them independently.

This is a node/npm issue itself as it kind of forces you to download the same package multiple times, but at least it's easy to know which version your package uses.

Comment: This is not what I'm asking at all. My question is specific to running scripts from a package.json using `npm` and the binaries created by `npm install`. Your answer addresses a very different thing

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood what you were asking, sorry for that. I'm checking if it's possible.

Comment: How about installing those packages globally ?

Comment: That's a big no. Those packages have specific version and dependencies specific to the project that can be different from the global versions. Also having them global makes it harder for portability

Comment: It depends how is your setup. Using docker for example having packages installed globally doesn't pose any problem.

Comment: :) that's assuming if I'm using docker, which I'm definitely not doing. Anyway, if you can think of a way to do what I'm asking with the limitations I've provided, let me know

Comment: Only thing I can see is creating a shell script called npm, place it in a folder in your PATH and remove npm from your PATH and have your shell script set the parent binary dir in your PATH and call the npm binary passing the rest of args. It's not really worth it, I would just add all those binaries your scripts in nested folders depend on in their own package.json, which in some ways is worth it, specially if you want to deploy them independently.

Comment: This is too convoluted and might not work on CI (i.e. Travis). The binaries in parent directories are just common to all subdirectories, and they're `devDependencies`. That's why they're all in a parent directory

Comment: I know, but in your npm script, all you can do is put the full path to the binaries, which I agree with you sucks :)